# Search Engine AND OR NOT () query parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, search

I am building a little searchengine and for that, I need a phrase query system. I am look for a good solution to solve it.

Let's say, we have the following queries:

```
[
  "Hello",
  "Hello AND World",
  "Hello OR !World",
  "(!Hello AND World) OR (foo AND bar)"
]
```

I'd look for the terms in my database and then intersect / union / not etc. them. But the problem is in finding a good function which queries them.

My first approach was with string splicing, finding etc, it kinda works if the pattern does not change hugely. But I want to develope a resursive function doing all the parsing itself, but unfortunately, I suck at recursive functions and hope, you can help me.

```
function regExingBrackets(s) {
    let res = [];
    let re = /\((.*?)\)/gm;
    let m;
    while (m = re.exec(s)) {
        res.push(m[1]);
    }
    return res;
}

function parseQuery(str) {
    let andorparser = /(.+)\s(OR|AND)\s(.+)/gm
    let res = andorparser.exec(str);
    // res[1] first term, 2 -> OR / AND, 3 -> second term
}
```

These functions have to be connected somehow and it has to go first the way down, like starting with !Hello (get all elements in database but hello), its result AND'ing with World (get all World elements and intersect these) and at the same time AND the other two words and their results OR'ing.

So it's parsing and using a function at the same time in the recursive funktion >.<

What would be a good solution for that problem? I am very happy and thankful for your help!

Kind Regards
TehEbil

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved my question. I've found a calculator somewhere and rewrote it to use its parser for my usecases.

```
  const ParserObj = new Parser();

  let resp = ParserObj.parse("((hel & lo) & World) & bar");  // not working
  //let resp = ParserObj.parse("((hel & lo) & World)"); //  working example
  let str = makeIntersect(resp);
  console.log("str", JSON.stringify(str, null, 2));
  let str2 = transformParseToIntersect(str);
  console.log("str2", str2);
```

[link to plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s8dNE6MCpfnpr81nKwpc?p=preview)

if the search keys are connected with the same symbol, for example &, I want them to be connected, like:

```
["hel", "lo", "world", "bar", "&"]
```

but instead, it becomes to:

```
[["hel", "lo", "&"], "world", "bar", "&"]
```

same problem when mixing it with |.

Reason for simplification is - I want to intersect the search keys. Intersection of multiple keys is faster than intersecting pairs and their results with another world/pair.

I hope my parser can help someone who has the same problem on the one hand, and on the other hand I hope someoen will be able to help me with my next problem.